# PHP return array if breaking chain in singleton

Tags: php, method-chaining

I've built a singleton class with chaining methods (to be used in a template).

To make chaining work I need to return `new static`. It allows the next chain to be added. The problem I have is that I don't want to return the static object if there are no more chains.

**Example**

```
<?php
class bread {
  public static $array;
  public static function blueprints() {
    static::$array = array('some', 'values');
    return new static;
  }
  public static function fields() {
    return static::$array;
  }
}

$blueprints = bread::blueprints();
$fields = bread::blueprints()->fields();

print_r($blueprint) // Returns object - FAIL
print_r($fields ) // Returns array - OK
```

In the example above I want `$blueprints` to return an array, because there are no more methods chained on it.

How can that be done?

Comment: A method cannot know how its output will be used. How about `$a = B::c(); $a->d()`? There's no sane way to detect that. You're also badly mixing up static and non-static calls. Not a sane approach at all.

Comment: @deceze By experience I know you are always right. I thought about doing something like this `bread::blueprint('projects', 'en')->fields('title')->value('label');` to have it as a one-liner, but I probably need to go with an argument array instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is you cannot do what you want.
Method chaining is not a special thing for Php.
For your example

```
bread::blueprints()->fields();
```

This is not different than:

```
$tmp = bread::blueprints();
$tmp->fields();
```

So because of the Php does not know the context where the result will be used of it cannot change the return type.
Here is another version of this question:
[Check if call is method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236659/check-if-call-is-method-chaining)

However, your class can implement [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.This will allow you to treat the object like an array without casting and you get total control over how the members are used.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:
$blueprints = (array)bread::blueprints();

Comment: Nice try, but it will result in an empty array in this case. (I'm not responsible for the downvote).